# Regarding layout weight and margins

Tags: android, android-layout-weight

Why when i set the attribute `layout_marginStart="130dp"` of the `button` the whole upper `EditText` shifts accordingly?

2- I'm planning to have the screen divided into 4 sections, the total `weight = 9` and sections 1,2,3,4 should has 2/9,2/9,4/9,1/9  accordingly. Please let me know if i need to modify something.

***XML***:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="9"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

<TableLayout 
    android:id="@+id/table_0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="4">
    <TableRow 
        android:id="@+id/row0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/tv_ip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:text="IP: "/>
        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/et_ip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="12"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow 
        android:id="@+id/row1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/tv_port"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:text="Port: "/>
        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/et_port"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="12"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow 
        android:id="@+id/row2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/tv_clientid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:text="Client_ID"/>
        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/et_clientid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="12"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow 
        android:id="@+id/row3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/tv_cleansession"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:text="Clean Session"/>
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbx_cleansession"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow 
        android:id="@+id/row4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_conn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="130dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Connect"/>
        </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

1 . End your Layout from bottom

```
</LenearLayout>
```

2. you have max your api virsion is 17 use of  `android:layout_marginStart="5dp"` . If you want to not change your api virsion then use this `android:layout_marginLeft=5dp`.
3. Dont use textview Showing Clean Session. Use this.

   `

   ```
       <CheckBox
           android:id="@+id/cbx_cleansession"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:text="Clean Session"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
   </TableRow>`
   ```
4. Last one i thing is you can use only EditText and give it Hint. and if you want to make it better then you can use background templates .

That's it. I hope you like it

Comment: but now, the space/gap between the ip2textview2 and its edittext is big, i.e: ip__________________________________________edittext2starts here"